# Recursividade e Haskell

Tags: recursão, haskell

Como definir recursivamente em termos da multiplicação, a função potência, onde uma base é elevada a um expoente inteiro não negativo?

Código:

```
expo (x, y) y > 0 fun(pot) return x*expo(x, y-1)
```

Comment: O que você fez até agora?

Comment: expo (x, y)
y > 0

fun(pot)
return x*expo(x, y-1)

Comment: Viu lá BulletSentence eu coloquei direto na pergunta, se pode editar e fazer o mesmo blz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menos compacto mas funciona.

```
potencia:: Int->Int->Int
potencia x n  |(n<0) = error "Expoente negativo."
              |(n==0) = 1
              |(n==1) = x
potencia x n = x * potencia x (n-1)
```